# Is there a name for matrices that are symmetric along the cross diagonal?

Tags: matrices, terminology, symmetric-matrices

Something like

$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b & c\\
    b & d & e\\
    c & e & f
\end{bmatrix}
$$

would be a symmetric matrix because the values are reflected along the diagonal, and $A=A^\intercal$

Is there a name for a matrix that's symmetric along the cross diagonal? Something like

$$
B=
\begin{bmatrix}
    c & b & a\\
    e & d & b\\
    f & e & c
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: You're right. I tried searching, but it's difficult to find without knowing the terminology in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Wikipedia is to be believed, then this is a [persymmetric matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persymmetric_matrix).

From the linked article:

> In mathematics, persymmetric matrix may refer to:
>   1. a square matrix which is symmetric in the northeast-to-southwest diagonal; or
>   2. a square matrix such that the values on each line perpendicular to the main diagonal are the same for a given line.

Comment: The text cited actually gives two possible definitions, with only the first one being relevant in this case.